# Python Behave test causing rhel 7 server to hang

Tags: python, linux, behave

On executing set of behave tests on linux server manually the behave tests are getting stuck at some random behave test and rest other behaves are not executed. There is no particular bdd which is giving issue. It causes the server to hang. How should i troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- I have observed this few weeks before on Linux box and windows server for behave tests
- I have started executing the python behave tests in small set of tests on multiple nodes instead of running on one
- This worked for me and now I have not observed any test causes the server to hang in between

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first check the logs for errors, this will give you correct information what causing the test to get stuck. if you do not find anything there then check the below:-

- System resource, is it running out of memory ?
- Are you using any infinite loop in your code ?
- Run the failed test cases individually to check if that are passing or
  not ?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Check the logs: Look at the logs generated by the behave tests and see if there are any error messages or exceptions that can help explain why the test is hanging.
2. Monitor system resources: Monitor the system resources such as CPU, memory, and disk usage during the test execution to see if the system is overloading.
3. Debug the code: If the logs and system resources do not provide any clues, you can try to debug the code by adding print statements or using a debugger to step through the code.
4. Try running the test in isolation: Try running the problematic test in isolation to see if it hangs when run alone. If it does, it may be a problem with the test itself.
5. Check for compatibility issues: Check if there are any compatibility issues between the behave framework and the server's operating system or other components.
6. Update dependencies: Make sure you have the latest version of all dependencies and libraries used by the behave tests.
7. Reinstall behave: If all else fails, you can try reinstalling the behave framework to see if it resolves the issue.